# Stop onDestroy on Scene Load.Unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a script that adds money when enemy dies (onDestroy). But when the scene changes that also destroys the enemies and adds money. **How I can make it only add money when enemy is destroyed by health=0  and not on scene change?**
Code:

```
void onDestroy()
{
AddCoins(Coins);
}
```

Comment: Use something different to `OnDestroy` but rather a proper event handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two main ways to do this :

- If it's possible, call the AddCoins Method in the code that calls Destroy() when health =0 instead of in OnDestroy(). Something like :

```
    if(health == 0){
       AddCoins(coins);
       Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

and no OnDestroy method.

- Otherwise, you could set a variable to true just before loading a new scene, and in OnDestroy() check if this variable is false, and only then adding coins.

If it's compatible with your game, I would recommend for the first solution, much cleaner in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scene.isLoaded` to only check the times when the scene is loaded and is not changing.

```
void OnDestroy()
{
    if(gameObject.scene.isLoaded)
    {
        AddCoins(Coins);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make it so that the `AddCoin()` method gets called not on destroy but instead have a check either in the update loop or ideally in your enemy damage function so it gets called only when health changes.

```
void Update()
{
   if(health == 0)
   {
      AddCoins(Coins)
      Destroy(gameobject)
   }
}
```

if you want to use your existing code structure and still have it be called onDestory you could add another check

```
void onDestroy()
{
   if(health == 0)
   {
     AddCoins(Coins);
   }

}
```

Comment: The second one work, but the first one addcoins every frame.